# How can i convert this query to eloquent structured query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can i convert this query to laravel eloquent query I have to attach some more relationships and where clauses to it.

**Query**

```
DB::select("SELECT `id` FROM `orders`
                WHERE (`start_time`, `end_time`) IN (
                SELECT `start_time`, `end_time`  FROM `orders`
                GROUP BY `start_time`, `end_time`
                HAVING COUNT(*) >= $timeSlotData->time_slot_max_limit)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see it in big picture
solve it step by step

first you can use
[method-wherein](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-wherein)

second add [groupBy](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-eloquent-group-by-exampleexample.html)

third use [HAVING](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#havingraw-orhavingraw)

Comment: how would i pass two columns to whereIn ?

Comment: actually you can't do this @Wcan but see those links will help you

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/where-in-multiple-columns?reply=401027

https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1021